# how to retrieve the namespace of an ontology loaded by rdflib

Tags: python, rdf, owl, rdflib

I created an ontology and now I want to read it using rdflib. the question is how to get the URI (namespace) or the prefix of the loaded graph with out manually inspecting the ontology as below:

```
from rdflib import *

rdf_address="C:/Users/eh/ontologies/RNO_V5042/NVDB_RNO_V5042_RDF.owl"
g=Graph()
g.parse(rdf_address)

for namespace in g.namespaces():
    print namespace

rno = Namespace("http://www.semanticweb.org/eh/ontologies/2015/3/RNO_V5042#") ###### **how to find this namespace?**

aClass = rno.Node
roundabout= rno.Roundabout
namedIndividual = URIRef('http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual')
rdftype = URIRef("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type")
for triple in g.triples((None,rdftype,rno.Roundabout)):
    print triple
```

Comment: **"the question is how to get the URI (namespace) or the prefix of the loaded graph with out manually inspecting the ontology"**  There are a few different concepts here.  OWL ontologies can be identified by an IRI.  That's the ontology IRI of the ontology.  Then, entities mentioned in the ontology can be identified by IRIs, and it's common practice to abbreviate some of these, when possible, by defining some IRI as a prefix and concatenating with a suffix (e.g., ex:foo), but there may be lots of these prefixes used in an ontology, and the prefixes are only serialization artifacts, not part...

Comment: ...of the ontology itself.  What do you mean when you say the "the URI (namespace) or the prefix of the loaded graph" ? Based on your code, it looks like you're looking for what's probably the ontology IRI, followed by a `#`.  We can't be sure of that, though, unless you post the ontology, too.  Could you post the ontology, please?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: when I develop an ontology, there probably are some concepts that I have defined in my ontology so my ontology will have a URI for itself that I can point at its defined concepts, right?  Now, I want to read the ontology in my code and assign a class name for a query. irrespective to what ontology is, my code is reading it and parsing but then I need to add the name space manually. more studying about the issue, i read sth about preferredUri or label!!!!

Comment: it should be a module of rdflib for a graph that I don't know!!!!!

Comment: *"there probably are some concepts that I have defined in my ontology so my ontology will have a URI for itself that I can point at its defined concepts, right?"*  Unfortunately, it's **not** as simple as that.  You can have an ontology with *no* ontology URI that defines lots of concepts.  They could have a common URI prefix, or they might not.  You can have an ontology *with* an ontology URI that defines lots of concepts, but there's no reason that they have to be identified by URIs that are prefixed by the ontology URI.  Extracting the ontology URI from an ontology, if it exists, is easy...

Comment: ...but if the ontology doesn't have a URI, then finding a "commonly used prefix" or something like that will be much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Having a rdflib Graph, parse() it and use MyNameSpace(g). This gives the namespace for empty prefix, i.e., ":".

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph() 
cOntoFile = "MyOnto.ttl"
g.parse(cOntoFile, format="turtle")

print(MyNameSpace(g))

def MyNameSpace(g):
  for ns_prefix, namespace in g.namespaces():
    if not ns_prefix:
      return namespace
  return ""
```

Comment: You may need also import rdflib.